# replace with actual word in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string.

```
x = %q{ On the server side, my EJB3 application uses Spring for configuring all sorts of things. So my EJBs all look up various ApplicationContexts and use them as a sort of...well, I was going to say poor man's JNDI, but the reality is that JNDI in the J2EE environment is really a poor man's Spring. :-)

On the GUI side, I use it instead of resource injection to get access to my EJBs. That lets me test the GUI component with simple pojos. So ejb is very good technology}
```

I am replacing the string `"ejb"`, case insensitive. I am doing this:

```
 y = x.gsub(/(ejb)/i, '<em>EJB</em>')
 # => " On the server side, my <em>EJB</em>3 application uses Spring for configuring all sorts of things. So my <em>EJB</em>s all look up various ApplicationContexts and use them as a sort of...well, I was going to say poor man's JNDI, but the reality is that JNDI in the J2EE environment is really a poor man's Spring. :-)\n\nOn the GUI side, I use it instead of resource injection to get access to my <em>EJB</em>s. That lets me test the GUI component with simple pojos. So <em>EJB</em> is very good technology"
```

I have a match in lower case: `"ejb"`, and I am replacing with this: `"<em>EJB</em>"`. How can I replace it without case change? I want `"<em>ejb</em>"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x.gsub(/(ejb)/i, '<em>\1</em>')
```

Comment: This is the best answer of the lot, as it doesn't rely on global variables.

Comment: +1 I wasn't even aware of such syntax! (I don't see it documented on the Regexp Doc page, anywhere I can learn more about it?)

Comment: Look at `String#gsub`, which is on the `String` page.

Comment: @sawa I asked second question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198602/truncate-line-before-and-after-cariage-return-r-or-new-line-n-with-ellipse, please let me know if you have solution

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
gsub(/(ejb)/i, "<em>#{$1}</em>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'test EjB123'.gsub(/ejb/i, "<em>#{$1}</em>")
 => "test <em>EjB</em>123"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
x.gsub!(/(ejb)/i) {|m| "<em>#{$~}<em>"}
```

There are a set of `Special global variables` set by the `Pattern matching`:

```
$~ is equivalent to ::last_match;
$& contains the complete matched text;
$` contains string before match;
$' contains string after match;
$1, $2 and so on contain text matching first, second, etc capture group;
$+ contains last capture group.
```

For more info: 
[Ruby Regex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html)