# truncate line before and after cariage return (\r) or new line (\n) with ellipses

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have this paragraph (may be I have more than one paragraph)

```
=> "On the server side,\n\nmy EJB3 application uses Spring for configuring all sorts of things. So,\n\nmy EJBs all look up various ApplicationContexts and use them as a sort of\r\nwell, I was going to say poor man's JNDI, but the reality is that JNDI in the J2EE environment is really a poor man's Spring. :-)\n\nOn the GUI side,\n\nI use it instead of resource injection to get access to my EJBs.\n\nThat lets me test the GUI component with simple pojos.\n\nHope that helps."
```

on `irb`, I am assign it into `x`

```
x = %q{On the server side,\n\nmy EJB3 application uses Spring for configuring all sorts of things. So,\n\nmy EJBs all look up various ApplicationContexts and use them as a sort of\r\nwell, I was going to say poor man's JNDI, but the reality is that JNDI in the J2EE environment is really a poor man's Spring. :-)\n\nOn the GUI side,\n\nI use it instead of resource injection to get access to my EJBs. \n\nThat lets me test the GUI component with simple pojos.\n\nHope that helps.}
```

as per carriage return (\r) and new line (\n), I need only these details from above paragraph, any Idea How can I do that?

```
my EJB3 application uses Spring for configuring all sorts of things. So,...my EJBs all look up various ApplicationContexts and use them as a sort of...I use it instead of resource injection to get access to my EJBs....
```

very simple way - let's say I have `a\nabc\r\nd\r\nab\neba` and search keyword is `b`, I need only `abcabeba`

Comment: @sawa - let's say my keyword is 'EJB', so I need to truncate that word base on nearest \r or \n, example - here is the string a\nabc\r\nd\r\nab\neba and search keyword is "b", I need only abcabeba

Comment: @sawa also update question

Comment: Is it *REALLY* necessary to have such long sample text? The idea is to have the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem you want help with. Anything beyond that is clutter and visual noise and gets in the way of our helping you.

Comment: @theTinMan - you are saying very good point, I will take care for my next question, I am sorry for this trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how `<em>\1</em>` is relevant here, but probably, you want this, I suppose.

```
x.scan(/.*ejb.*/i).join("...")
```

Note that the regex is in single-line mode.

Or, if you are doing this on Linux, and still need to deal with (not only `\n` but also) `\r`,  then this might be safer:

```
x.scan(/[^\n\r]*ejb[^\n\r]*/i).join("...")
```

Comment: yes, it is relevant here, first I am replacing (that you answered yesterday), after that I am searching

Comment: multi-line mode means? Do you have some example of link? for my knowledge

Comment: Please google it. In multi-line mode, `.` matches any character. Otherwise, `.` matches any character besides end line character.

Comment: I removed string replacement, you are right, replacement process is irrelevant to the question here

Comment: Sorry, I should have said single-line mode, not "not multi-line mode".

Comment: see my last comment on @Darshan Computing, something I am looking for

Comment: Okay if you understand. And, I think my code satisfies your condition.

Comment: Please don't take it -ve, I thought let me explain what I am looking for, once again I am sorry

Comment: I think the issue is a stray `\r`.  Is that right, @RobertGoldman?  It can be stripped out with `strip`: `x.scan(/.*ejb.*/i).map{|s| s.strip}.join('...')`

Comment: @DarshanComputing I came to the same idea about the issue. I updated the answer.

Comment: DarshanComputing  and sawa, now it is working for me, you guys are great, also learnt ruby and as well as passion from you guys, most important thing How to answer on stack overflow and help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = eval("%q{a\nabc\r\nd\r\nab\neba}")
p s.split("\n").select{|x| x.include? 'b'}.join('')
#=>"abcabeba"
```

Comment: for single words it is working fine, let's say s= "banana\n\rapple\nmango\rapple\n\norange\rapple" and I am searching "apple"